# resetting the position of the mouse in script that moves the camera in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First off I'm very new to Unity so bear with me. I have a drop down menu that changes to different cameras when the user wants to change camera view. The problem I have with this is that if you change the view at all like using the mouse wheel to zoom in or out the view stays zoomed in or out still when you change cameras, instead of resetting to the starting position when you switch cameras. I would like to make it so when you change cameras the starting position of the mouse resets. I have a function called "reset()" in my script that handles mouse movement that I call from a different script that when you change the cameras with the drop down I want it to reset the starting variables back to the starting position. Any guidance on this would be much appreciated. The reset function is at the bottom of my code. I am trying to store the starting position in private Vector3 positionStore; and trying to execute transform.position = positionStore; to do the actual transformation.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/3dsMax Camera Style")]
public class maxCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform target;
public Vector3 targetOffset;
public float distance = 5.0f;
public float maxDistance = 20;
public float minDistance = .6f;
public float xSpeed = 200.0f;
public float ySpeed = 200.0f;
public int yMinLimit = -80;
public int yMaxLimit = 80;
public int zoomRate = 40;
public float panSpeed = 0.3f;
public float zoomDampening = 5.0f;

private float xDeg = 0.0f;
private float yDeg = 0.0f;
private float currentDistance;
private float desiredDistance;
private Quaternion currentRotation;
private Quaternion desiredRotation;
private Quaternion rotation;
private Vector3 position;

private Quaternion currentRotationStore;
private Quaternion desiredRotationStore;
private Quaternion rotationStore;
private Vector3 positionStore;
Vector3 originalPos;

void Start() { Init(); }
void OnEnable() { Init(); }

public void Init()
{
    originalPos = new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.y, gameObject.transform.position.z);

    //If there is no target, create a temporary target at 'distance' from the cameras current viewpoint
    if (!target)
    {
        GameObject go = new GameObject("Cam Target");
        go.transform.position = transform.position + (transform.forward * distance);
        target = go.transform;
    }

    distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position);
    currentDistance = distance;
    desiredDistance = distance;

    //be sure to grab the current rotations as starting points.
    position = transform.position;
    rotation = transform.rotation;
    currentRotation = transform.rotation;
    desiredRotation = transform.rotation;

    //trying to store these values to be used later in reset
    positionStore = transform.position;
    currentRotationStore = transform.rotation;

    xDeg = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.right, transform.right);
    yDeg = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, transform.up);
}

/*
 * Camera logic on LateUpdate to only update after all character movement logic has been handled. 
 */
void LateUpdate()
{
    // If Control and Alt and Middle button? ZOOM!
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(2) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftAlt) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        desiredDistance -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * zoomRate * 0.125f * Mathf.Abs(desiredDistance);
    }
    // If middle mouse and left alt are selected? ORBIT
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(2) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftAlt))
    {
        xDeg += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * 0.02f;
        yDeg -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;

        ////////OrbitAngle

        //Clamp the vertical axis for the orbit
        yDeg = ClampAngle(yDeg, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);
        // set camera rotation 
        desiredRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yDeg, xDeg, 0);
        currentRotation = transform.rotation;

        rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(currentRotation, desiredRotation, Time.deltaTime * zoomDampening);
        transform.rotation = rotation;
    }
    // otherwise if middle mouse is selected, we pan by way of transforming the target in screenspace
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
    {
        //grab the rotation of the camera so we can move in a psuedo local XY space
        target.rotation = transform.rotation;
        target.Translate(Vector3.right * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * panSpeed);
        target.Translate(transform.up * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * panSpeed, Space.World);
    }

    ////////Orbit Position

    // affect the desired Zoom distance if we roll the scrollwheel
    desiredDistance -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * Time.deltaTime * zoomRate * Mathf.Abs(desiredDistance);
    //clamp the zoom min/max
    desiredDistance = Mathf.Clamp(desiredDistance, minDistance, maxDistance);
    // For smoothing of the zoom, lerp distance
    currentDistance = Mathf.Lerp(currentDistance, desiredDistance, Time.deltaTime * zoomDampening);

    // calculate position based on the new currentDistance 
    position = target.position - (rotation * Vector3.forward * currentDistance + targetOffset);
    transform.position = position;
}

private static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
{
    if (angle < -360)
        angle += 360;
    if (angle > 360)
        angle -= 360;
    return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
}

public void reset(){
    transform.position = positionStore;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your LateUpdate() is firing after your Reset(), and the desiredDistance parameter remains unchanged. What's happening is you reset the position of your game object, but in the LateUpdate(), the position is being set back the zoomed distance. You'll want to reset your desiredDistance in your Reset() method. It will fixed your problem.